# Should I use a jQuery dialog or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface

I have a list of user posts on a page and there is an icon in the top right of each post.  When the user hovers over the icon I want to display additional info about the post, e.g. date, time, author, etc.

I want to display the additional information in an overlay of some kind, and I'm wondering if I should use a jQuery dialog widget or just some javascript.  I don't think jQuery tooltips will do the trick, because some of the details are quite long.

Some specifics:

- The details should show on hover and disappear when the pointer moves away
- The overlay does not need to be modal.  It does not require a title bar.
- It should appear at the current location of the pointer and should automatically size to fit the content

So, should I be looking at the jQuery dialog widget?  Or simply a javascript solution?

Thanks..!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A temporal, non-modal dialog positioned next to the user's cursor is effectively a tooltip. I'd check out one of the more advanced jQuery tooltip plugins like [qTip2](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/). It can accomodate many different types of content (images, paragraphs, videos) and is great at scaling to fit large content.

The [AJAX example](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/demos/#ajax) on the demo page should be of particular interest to you.

Good luck!